# Installing prerequisites giving me errors

Tags: installation, sharepoint-server, prerequisites

I've been trying to install the prerequisites for Server 2010 but I keep getting errors in the installer.exe

I've tried downloading them manually and using the arguements.txt but that didn't work. I've tried using AutoSPSourceBuilder but I get an error when it tries isntalling officeserver-sp1.

This is the log I get when running the installer:

```
2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Processor architecture is (9)
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Reading the following string value/name...
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Common Startup
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - from the following registry location...
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - The value is... 
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Trying to remove the startup task if there is any.
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\SharePointServerPreparationToolStartup_0FF1CE14-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.cmd
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Error: Startup task doesn't exist. This is not a continuation after a restart.
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Locating the following command line arguments file:
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - C:\SP\2010\SharePoint\PrerequisiteInstaller.Arguments.txt
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Error: This file does not exist
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Details of the current operating system: 
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Major version number of the operating system:  (6)
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Minor version number of the operating system:  (2)
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Build number of the operating system:  (0X23F0=9200)
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Major version number of the latest Service Pack:  (0)
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Minor version number of the latest Service Pack:  (0)
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Platform ID of the operating system:  (2)
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Product suites available on the operating system:  (0X110=272)
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Product type of the operating system: VER_NT_SERVER
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Product type:  (7)
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Configuring the application's property sheet...
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Hotfix for Microsoft Windows (KB976462)
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Reading version of the following file...
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\System.IdentityModel.dll
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - GetFileVersionInfoSize failed (-2147024894)
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Windows Identity Foundation (KB974405)
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Reading the following string value/name...
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - 
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - from the following registry location...
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Identity Foundation\Setup\v3.5
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 (x64)
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Reading version of the following file...
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Synchronization\1.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.Synchronization.dll
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - GetFileVersionInfoSize failed (-2147024894)
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Microsoft Chart Controls for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Reading the following DWORD value/name...
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Install
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - from the following registry location...
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\NET Framework Chart Setup\NDP\v3.5
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Microsoft Filter Pack 2.0
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Check for a subkey matching the following pattern...
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - {*5140000-2000-****-1000-*000000FF1CE}
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - from the following registry location...
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Native Client
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Reading the following string value/name...
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Version
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - from the following registry location...
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\SQLNCLI10\CurrentVersion
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Analysis Services ADOMD.NET
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Reading the following string value/name...
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - DisplayVersion
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - from the following registry location...
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{68442820-C846-4E8A-8D53-EDEDD1511CDE}
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Microsoft Server Speech Platform Runtime (x64)
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Reading the following registry location...
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - TypeLib\{D3C4A7F2-7D27-4332-B41F-593D71E16DB1}\A.0\0\win64
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Microsoft Server Speech Recognition Language - TELE(en-US)
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Reading the following registry location...
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech Server\v10.0\Recognizers\Tokens\SR_MS_en-US_TELE_10.0
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - SQL 2008 R2 Reporting Services SharePoint 2010 Add-in
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Reading the following string value/name...
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - Version
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - from the following registry location...
    2013-07-17 09:53:26 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Report Server SharePoint Addin\CurrentVersion
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - Beginning download/installation
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - Created thread for installer
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - "C:\Windows\system32\ServerManagerCmd.exe" -inputpath "C:\Users\sp_admin\AppData\Local\Temp\PreE055.tmp.XML"
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - Error: Unable to install (2)
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - Error: [In HRESULT format] (-2147024894)
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - Last return code (2)
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - Error: The tool was unable to install Application Server Role, Web Server (IIS) Role.
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - Last return code (2)
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - Options for further diagnostics: 1. Look up the return code value 2. Download the prerequisite manually and verify size downloaded by the prerequisite installer. 3. Install the prerequisite manually from the given location without any command line options.
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - Cannot retry
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - Hotfix for Microsoft Windows (KB976462)
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - Reading version of the following file...
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\System.IdentityModel.dll
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - GetFileVersionInfoSize failed (-2147024894)
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - Windows Identity Foundation (KB974405)
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - Reading the following string value/name...
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - 
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - from the following registry location...
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Identity Foundation\Setup\v3.5
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 (x64)
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - Reading version of the following file...
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Synchronization\1.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.Synchronization.dll
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - GetFileVersionInfoSize failed (-2147024894)
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - Microsoft Chart Controls for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - Reading the following DWORD value/name...
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - Install
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - from the following registry location...
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\NET Framework Chart Setup\NDP\v3.5
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - Microsoft Filter Pack 2.0
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - Check for a subkey matching the following pattern...
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - {*5140000-2000-****-1000-*000000FF1CE}
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - from the following registry location...
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Native Client
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - Reading the following string value/name...
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - Version
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - from the following registry location...
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\SQLNCLI10\CurrentVersion
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Analysis Services ADOMD.NET
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - Reading the following string value/name...
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - DisplayVersion
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - from the following registry location...
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{68442820-C846-4E8A-8D53-EDEDD1511CDE}
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - Microsoft Server Speech Platform Runtime (x64)
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - Reading the following registry location...
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - TypeLib\{D3C4A7F2-7D27-4332-B41F-593D71E16DB1}\A.0\0\win64
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - Microsoft Server Speech Recognition Language - TELE(en-US)
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - Reading the following registry location...
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech Server\v10.0\Recognizers\Tokens\SR_MS_en-US_TELE_10.0
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - SQL 2008 R2 Reporting Services SharePoint 2010 Add-in
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - Reading the following string value/name...
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - Version
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - from the following registry location...
    2013-07-17 09:53:31 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Report Server SharePoint Addin\CurrentVersion
    2013-07-17 09:53:34 - Opening log file
    2013-07-17 09:53:34 - Opened action for user
    2013-07-17 09:53:34 - C:\Users\sp_admin\AppData\Local\Temp\PrerequisiteInstaller.2013.07.17-09.53.26.log
```

Answer (score 2):

On error line 10-12 the AutoSPInstaller is trying to locate the PrerequisiteIntaller.arguments.txt which is missing. Rename you arguments.txt to PrerequisiteIntaller.arguments.txt and run AutoSPInstaller again.

It is common to get errors running the installation, but just read the error messages and solve problems as you move along.

I usually run AutoSPInstaller five to ten times on a new server before I get it right.